# ionic sliding menu click gets selected but does not slide open menu onto screen

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

My sliding menu for the app does not do anything when you click on  the menu button not sure what I am missing.  It creates the button for the sliding menu and when you click it registers that it has been clicked but does not have the menu slide onto the screen. Sorry for this basic question I am new to ionic and angular JS.  Not sure where I am going wrong in this because I am following ionic documentation on how to add their sliding menu into the app.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">

  <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleSideMenu">
    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
  </button>



  <h1 class="title">TekIT</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content scroll="false">
      <map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-tabs>

      <ion-tab title="Mac" icon-off="ion-social-apple" icon-on="ion-social-apple" href="#/app/search">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-search"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Windows" icon-off="ion-social-windows" icon-on="ion-social-windows" href="#/app/browse">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-browse"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Mobile" icon-off="ion-iphone" icon-on="ion-iphone" href="#/app/playlists">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-playlists"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab title="Other" icon-off="ion-wifi" icon-on="ion-wifi"" href="#/app/playlists">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-playlists"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
    </ion-footer-bar>
  </body>
</html>
```

menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>


      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!-- TABS -->
    <ion-tabs>

      <ion-tab title="Search" icon-off="ion-search" icon-on="ion-search" href="#/app/search">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-search"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Browse" icon-off="ion-ios-glasses" icon-on="ion-ios-glasses" href="#/app/browse">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-browse"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Playlist" icon-off="ion-ipod" icon-on="ion-ipod" href="#/app/playlists">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-playlists"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>

  </ion-side-menu-content>

   <!-- Side Menu (left) -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
          Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
          Search
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
          Browse
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
          Playlists
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

//toggleSideMenu
.controller('toggleSideMenu', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.alert("TEST!");
})

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
  $scope.toggleSideMenu = function() {
      alert("TEST!");
  };

  $scope.mapCreated = function(map) {
    $scope.map = map;
  };


  $scope.centerOnMe = function () {
    console.log("Centering");
    if (!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
      console.log('Got pos', pos);
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function (error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };
})
```